# SQLServer Exception: Invalid column name

Tags: java, sql, exception, jdbc, sql-server-2012

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Invalid column name 'IDPaciente'
```

I am getting this exception. This is my code:

```
    String query = "INSERT INTO Paciente('IDPaciente', 'NomePaciente', 'IdadePaciente', 'LocalidadePaciente') VALUES('"+IDTextField.getText()+"', '"+NomeTextField.getText()+"', '"+IdadeTextField.getText()+"', '"+LocalidadeTextField.getText()+"')";
    try
    {
        st = con.DatabaseConnection().createStatement();
        rs = st.executeQuery(query);
    }
```

I suspect the problem might be in the query itself.

I have searched a lot and couldn't find the solution to my problem. I have tried refreshing the cache, changing permissions within the schema, restarting sql server (I am using sql server management studio 2012), I am correctly connected to my database, and nothing seems to work.

What could I be doing wrong?
Thank you!

Comment: Remove all quetes ' '

Comment: did u tried to execute the code against SSMS directly , is raising the same error ?

Comment: @RyanTuosto It has a column named "IDPaciente", yes

Comment: @ahmedabdelqader Yes, I have tried to execute it directly and it gives the same error

Comment: `'` is for quoting *text literals*, not column names. Remove all the apostrophes, and use a `PreparedStatement` and `?` parameter markers, not String concatenation.

Comment: @Gazelle, So Remove the quotes as we said, for more details, go to below answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove quotes , try :

```
String query = "INSERT INTO Paciente(IDPaciente, NomePaciente, IdadePaciente, LocalidadePaciente) VALUES('"+IDTextField.getText()+"', '"+NomeTextField.getText()+"', '"+IdadeTextField.getText()+"', '"+LocalidadeTextField.getText()+"')";
try
{
    st = con.DatabaseConnection().createStatement();
    rs = st.executeQuery(query);
}
```

Remove also quotes for `INT` values.

Comment: made some progress but it's still not working. Taking out the quotes give some kind of different errors. If I insert a value like "John" it says I have an incorrect syntax near "John" or "John" is an invalid column name. Oops let me check it first, didnt see your edit.

Comment: Keep the quotes for the `Strig` values

Comment: @Gazelle That is because string literals should be enclosed in single-quotes (not double quotes). But the real solution is provided in the answer by YCF_L: do not use string concatenation, use prepared statements with parameters.

Comment: @Sami one more thing, why does the statement not returning a result set in this context? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

Your code is not secure, you can easily get Syntax error or SQL Injection I suggest to use PreparedStatement instead.

You have a problem in your Query, the columns should not be between `''` so you can use this instead :

```
String query = "INSERT INTO Paciente(IDPaciente, NomePaciente, IdadePaciente, "
        + "LocalidadePaciente) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)";

try (PreparedStatement insert = con.prepareStatement(query)) {
    insert.setString(1, IDTextField.getText());
    insert.setString(2, NomeTextField.getText());
    insert.setString(3, IdadeTextField.getText());
    insert.setString(4, LocalidadeTextField.getText());

    insert.executeUpdate();
}
```

If one of your column is an int you have to use `setInt`, if date `setDate`, and so on.

Answer (score 3):

You have four problems, though only the first is giving you the current error:

1. Single-quotes (`'`) are for quoting text literals, not column names. In MS SQL Server, you can quote column names using double-quotes (`"`) or square brackets (`[]`), but you don't need to quote them at all.
2. To prevent [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks, where hackers will **steal your data and delete your tables**, and to prevent potential syntax errors, **never** build a SQL statement with user-entered strings, using string concatenation. Always use a [`PreparedStatement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html).
3. Always clean up your resources, preferably using [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html).
4. Don't use [`executeQuery()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeQuery--) for an `INSERT` statement. Use [`executeUpdate()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeUpdate--). As the javadoc says:

   > Executes the SQL statement in this PreparedStatement object, which must be an SQL Data Manipulation Language (DML) statement, such as **`INSERT`**, `UPDATE` or `DELETE`; or an SQL statement that returns nothing, such as a DDL statement.

So, your code should be:

```
String query = "INSERT INTO Paciente" +
              " (IDPaciente, NomePaciente, IdadePaciente, LocalidadePaciente)" +
              " VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";
try (PreparedStatement st = con.DatabaseConnection().prepareStatement(query)) {
    st.setString(1, IDTextField.getText());
    st.setString(2, NomeTextField.getText());
    st.setString(3, IdadeTextField.getText());
    st.setString(4, LocalidadeTextField.getText());
    st.executeUpdate();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the quotes from your column names.

```
"INSERT INTO Paciente(IDPaciente, NomePaciente, IdadePaciente, LocalidadePaciente) VALUES('"+IDTextField.getText()+"', '"+NomeTextField.getText()+"', '"+IdadeTextField.getText()+"', '"+LocalidadeTextField.getText()+"')"
```

Answer (score 0):

The Column names are does not typed within quotes, Remove them and try again.

**Demo:-**

```
Create table MyTable (id int , name varchar (50))
go
insert into MyTable (id,name) values (1 , 'ahmed')
```

Result:-

```
(1 row(s) affected)
```

Try insert them again with quotes.

```
insert into MyTable ('id','name') values (1 , 'ahmed')
```

Result:-

```
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
Invalid column name 'id'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
Invalid column name 'name'.
```